# Centering a non-defined number of images

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

For a school project, I need to do some kind of card game.
So I'm trying to center the "hand" on top and the "played cards" just under them, but it can contain 1 or several cards, and I just cant understand what I'm suppose to do.
I have (I'm using Bootstrap if that can help):

```
<div class="row">
    <div id="hand" class="text-center">
        <img class="img-hand" src="../img/dos_carte.jpg">
        <img class="img-hand"  src="../img/dos_carte.jpg">
    </div>
    <div id="played" class="text-center">
        <img class="img-played" src="../img/1-guard.jpg">
        <img class="img-played" src="../img/7-countess.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS

```
.text-center {
 text-align:center
}
.img-hand{
  height: 80%;
  width: 20%;
  display:inline-block;
}
.img-played{
  height: 100%;
  width: 25%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

This code works just fine when there's the same amount of cards, but when I try something like 1 in hand + 2 played, it's not centered anymore. I'd also like the cards to shrink when you play too many cards (the total width should always be the same after x cards).

edit: my problem in this case is that my div `hand` is smaller then `played`when there's less cards (maybe to keep the  proportionality or something?), it don't take the full width of the `row`

I really hope I'm not asking for too much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to use js to effect the width of the images depending on the number of images in each box. Should be easy as you must have a count of the cards.

If `hand` and `played` are next to each other, you may want to set their widths so that they are the same regardless of the number of cards in either box (ie `col-sm-6`).

Comment: That's what I expected, I might indeed need to change the css dynamically
Using `col-md-12` forced the div to take the full width, and that's exactly what I wanted.
Thanks a lot for the advices, I think I have the solutions to my problems!